How to make the object to follow the player and the spot light to be rotating smooth lighting the player?
at the top of the script i added these variables.
public Transform target;
public float chaseSpeed = 5f;
public float chaseRotationSpeed = 5f;
public float followDistance = 2f;
private Transform spotlight;

ins the Start
void Start()
{
    // Cache the spotlight reference
    spotlight = GameObject.Find("Spot Light").transform;
}

in the Update
void Update()
{
  if (isChasing)
 {
    ChasePlayer();
 }
}

and ChasePlayer method
void ChasePlayer()
{
    autoMove = false;

    // Calculate the target position to keep a certain distance from the player
    Vector3 targetPosition = player.position - (player.position - transform.position).normalized * followDistance;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, chaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Smoothly rotate the spotlight to look at the player
    Vector3 lightDirection = player.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion lightRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lightDirection);

    if (spotlight != null)
    {
        spotlight.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(spotlight.rotation, lightRotation, Time.deltaTime * chaseRotationSpeed);
    }
}

what io want is that the drone will be always some distance behind the player and no matter the drone rotation and looking at the spot light children should always rotate smoothly at the player lighting the player.
but if for example i change the chaseRotationSpeed variable to 100 for some reason the drone is changing position and get stick on the player.  the drone is on the player position. but the chaseRotationSpeed should be only rotating the child spot light not changing the drone position.
if i don't try to change the chaseRotationSpeed then the spot light will never rotate enough and never spot on the player.
the spot light child object never rotating.  the spot light rotation stay on 0,0,0
and the drone it self also never follow the player from behind.
the script is attached to the Main (Cone) object.

and screenshot of the drone and the player.  the drone and the spot light are not even close to be behind the player and spot the player.
the drone and the spot light are in front of the player and never rotating looking at the player.  they are moving when i move the player but never follow and spot.


In your calculation for the target position you never define what "behind the player" means ... you always use the current existing offset direction Vector3 targetPosition = player.position - (player.position - transform.position).normalized * followDistance regardless of any rotation of the player ...

also is target == player ? or what is the difference/relationship between these?

Is your forward vector pointing in the direction of the light? That is the vector that will be aligned when you use LookRotation.
